# Web browser fails to connect to website after 100 refreshes on client

Tags: http, tcp, google-chrome, browser

I'm using an HTTP meta-refresh to execute a script multiple times.

After 100 refreshes, the browser stalls.

According to devtools, the browser doesn't even complete an initial connection to the server.

After this point I can't load any other pages from my website.

At first I thought this was a server side issue, however, if I switch to another browser, on the same device, I'm again able to access my website.

After some time, I'm again able to use the original browser to access the website.

I don't know enough to even begin to troubleshoot this problem. What might be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

It probably is your server or the hosting platform. Most hosting platforms have measures in place to prevent exactly what you are doing - spamming the site.

I know it is your own site, and what you are doing is legit, but there is no way for the website/hosting platform to know this. This is how websites can get taken down by DOS attacks. I would contact your hosting provider to ask them if they have anything like this in place, and if they do, how you can disable them.